# How to increase div's height with Zoom level/Screen resolution?

Tags: css, layout, html

Could anyone of you help me resolve this issue. I have to implement the following layout:

```
Root div

   -Header  
   -Content

Footer div
```

There should not be any gap between the `Root Div` and the Footer. And the Footer should always stick to the bottom of the web page. So basically, if I zoom out or increase the resolution, the Content Div should increase in height.

Can any of you please tell me how to achieve this?

---

The `div`s look like this:

```
<header>
    <container>
        <content> ---> Has a gradient background
           <text>
           <image> ---> The bottom end of this image should be behind the footer, and when the screen resolution changes, the complete image should  display with the Gradient background extended until the footer.
<footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty much always an illusion - being that when you expand your page you're not getting more content. http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ Putting a background image / color on your wrapper div would give you the likely result you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for teh tip. Actually I am able to stick the footer to the bottom, But I am not able to find a way to extend the content DIV when the window is zoomed out or the resolution is increased. Could you please give me a tip on that?

Answer (score 1):

Like so?:

```
<div id="root" style="height:100%;">
    Le root
</div>
<div id="footer" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;">Le Footer</div>
```